# Customs on Domestic Flights

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, domestic-travel

I am flying to Dallas from Australia then will connect to New York with a domestic airplanes do I go through customs in New York again

Comment: No, you clear customs at the first port of entry in the US, and will probably connect to a domestic terminal without customs or immigration.
Interestingly, I've been on domestic flights in Australia where you're told to throw away all fruit when landing (I flew from Sydney to NT when I saw this). It's true that some states (even in the US) forbid bringing fruit interstate. I found this when driving from Oregon to California - a man with a flashlight checked our car for fruit. 
But in the case of flying, no, I do not believe so.